# Xlsxwriter clear filter in protected sheet

Tags: python, vba, xlsxwriter

Im trying for hours to find out how to enable clearing the filter with xlsxwriter in a protected sheet.
Microsoft says that it won't work, but there are macros in VBA which are allowing it to do.
Since we are in python I wanted to ask if someone knows how to do it with the xlsxwriter.

Thanks in advance.

My settings.

```vb
if protect_sheet:
    worksheet.protect(
        options={
            "objects": False,
            "scenarios": False,
            "format_cells": True,
            "format_columns": True,
            "format_rows": False,
            "insert_columns": False,
            "insert_rows": False,
            "insert_hyperlinks": True,
            "delete_columns": False,
            "delete_rows": False,
            "select_locked_cells": True,
            "sort": True,
            "autofilter": True,
            "pivot_tables": False,
            "select_unlocked_cells": True,
        })
```

Comment: If Microsoft say it isn't possible, and there isn't an option to do this in Excel, then it is unlikely that it can be done via XlsxWriter.

Comment: I think there is an error on the last comma.  If so change ```"select_unlocked_cells": True,```  for ```"select_unlocked_cells": True``` without comma.